# awscli not able to make connection

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I installed awscli using bundled installer as suggested in the following link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html . The installation was successful , but am not able to make any connection by using commands. When am using testing commands like ,

**aws ec2 describe-regions**

there is no responds.
(1) Is it because of any port problem 
(2) I had already configured the aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, output, region details. Is there any other configuration I need to do make

regards,

Ajith

Comment: Try running with the ``--debug`` option to see what's going on.

Comment: I had tried  as you told and I got the following error,  ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(101, 'Network is unreachable'))
2015-09-24 10:45:51,226 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server? This sounds like a general networking problem unrelated to the AWSCLI.